# Reference Control Within Control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a custom ASP.NET control that I built (.ascx file).
This control contains some labels/textboxes/etc. as well as an "Ok" and "Cancel" button.

I would like to use the [AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) control to popup my custom control and let the user interact with it and press Ok/Cancel when finished.

The ModalPopup control has `OkControlID` and `CancelControlID` properties that can tell the popup when to close.

How can I reference the Ok/Cancel buttons from within my custom control?

I have tried adding properties to my control that return the buttons and then using dot-notation, but that does not appear to work.  Here is the basic outline:

Custom Control Code (partial):

```
public Button OkButton
{
    get { return this.btnOk; }
    set { }
}
```

Main Page:

```
<!-- This button should trigger the popup -->
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />

<!-- AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopup control ( -->
<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
    ID="btnEdit_ModalPopupExtender" 
    runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="btnEdit" 
    PopupControlID="ctlBasic"
    OkControlID="ctlBasic.OkButton" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<!-- This is my custom control that should be popped up -->
<uc1:ctlBasic ID="ctlBasic" runat="server" />
```

My goal is to be able to plug-in my custom control without any additional code from the parent.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the property to return `Button`, make it return the ID of the button, like below.

```
public String OkButtonID
{
    get
    {
        return this.btnOk.ID;
    }
}
```

And then make the change in your `aspx` markup for modalpopupextender as below.

```
<!-- AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopup control ( -->
<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
    ID="btnEdit_ModalPopupExtender" 
    runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="btnEdit" 
    PopupControlID="ctlBasic"
    OkControlID="ctlBasic.OkButtonID" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

`OKControlID` and `CancelControlID` are not really required. If you want to specify them, you can do it with underscore i.e. `YourUserControlID_ButtonIDInUserControl`.

Please note you do not need to make any control in your user public.